# Copying data between two struct pointers giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to copy the contains of a pointer to a struct to another pointer.

My struct:

```
typedef struct State {
  char alphabets[2][6]; 
  struct State *PREV; /*this points to the previous state it came from*/
  struct State *NEXT; /*this points to the next state in the linked list*/
  int cost; /*Number of moves done to get to this position*/
  int zero_index;/*this holds the index to the empty postion*/
  char *move[2];/*this holds the move that was done to get to this state*/
} State;
```

Memory allocation method:

```
State *memAllocator() {
  State *p = (State*)malloc(sizeof(State));
  if (p == NULL) {
    printf("Malloc for a new position failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  return p;
}
```

Here' an example of my Structs Alphabets

```
CANAMA
PANAL_
```

I have a randomize function that gives me the two possible moves of the state. The two moves for the above state would be

```
CANAM_
PANALA  
AND
CANAMA
PANA_L
```

In my randomize state function I copy the contains of my current state and then put it in the new state.

But here is the problem, I'm doing a breadth first search and trying to find out the shortest distance from the one state to another. In the process of doing I get pretty far in the search. But then it gives a segmentation fault at line where I copy the contains of current state to a new state.
I tried memcpy as well, but it gives the same segmentation fault. Here are the lines:

```
*new_state=*current_state;
/*memcpy(new_state, current_state, sizeof(State));*/
```

So, is the way I am copying my memory incorrect that is causing the problem. But if thats the case then why does it go for a while and then gives out a segmentation fault. Please help.

Here's a link to my full code. [Full Code](http://www.scribd.com/doc/117020157/PanamaCanal-c)

Comment: You probably are either accessing some memory that was already free'ed, or you are accessing some uninitialized memory - most likely either current_state or new_state is not pointing to a good memory location at the point of the segfault. I recommend using valgrind to sort this out.

Comment: Thanks for the valgrind recommendation. I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at least one of new_state and current_state is null. Best to change your printfs from `printf("If exception below then problem in swapN\n");` to `printf("If exception below then problem in swapN: %p %p\n", current_state, new_state1);` to see where this happens; but at least one possibility is the following:

```
printf("If exception below then problem in swap3\n"); 
new_state1 = swap(empty_index/10, (empty_index%10)-1,current_sta te, new_state1); 
printf("If this prints problem not in swap\n"); 
if (new_state1 != NULL){
    //... [REMOVED FOR CLARITY]
    return; 
} 
/*Go East*/ 
/*printf("Step %d, move %c west\n",current_state->alphabets[empt y_index/10][(empty_index%10)+1]);*/ 
printf("If exception below then problem in swap4\n"); 
new_state1 = swap(empty_index/10, (empty_index%10+1),current_state, new_state1);
```

Notice that the second call to swap() will ALWAYS have new_state1 be `NULL` (because you already returned it if's not null!)

Comment: if the first swap returns NULL then the second swap WILL NOT be null but will be a random state that isn't in the hash_table. I just want one state in new_state1 so I used the break if I don't get a null in the first swap.

Comment: But you're using new_state1, which you just wrote `NULL` to, as an argument to `swap`, not just for the output.

Comment: yes, I am passing a null new_state1 as an argument to swap because it is inside the method swap that I fill the values of current_state to new_state and make some further changes in new_state. Then the swap method checks if the state is in the hash_table if not then returns the new_state which is now filled up with data, if yes then returns NULL.

Comment: Fair enough. I still recommend checking (via `printf`) the actual pointer values at the time of the crash – a segfault means you're dereferencing illegal values (on one side or other of the assignment), and by far the most likely illegal value is `NULL`.

Comment: So, this is the pointer output I got right before the segmentation fault 
If exception below then problem in swap: 0x10c703900 0x0
It seems like the new_state1 is pointing to 0x0 which I assume is NULL

Comment: but, that whats its supposed to do. and in the next code
*new_state=*current_state;
the null memory will get filled with all the data in the current state!

Comment: I am currently looking into the output and all the other outputs of the prinf statements have complete memory outputs like 

If exception below then problem in swap: 0x10c702fd0 0x10c704540

So, seems like the problem is the fact that new_state1 is null